High latency at low data rates w/USB to Ethernet Adapter
We have designed a custom board that utilizes a USB Micro connector interface. We currently connect to the USB Micro connector using a USB Micro to Ethernet adapter to send data between our custom board and a PC. The USB interface is controlled by a TI Sitara Processor, which sends or receives the data to the outside world via the USB Micro to Ethernet adapter. We have encountered an issue in which the latency seems to to increase to over 500 ms when operating at low data rates (less than 500 kbps). At high data rates (anything over 1 Mbps), the latency is within our acceptable margins. I am trying to rule any hardware related issues that could be causing these latency issues at lower data rates. Has anyone else seen issues in which latency increases at low data rates? The USB protocol we are using is USB 2.0 and the adapter is a COTs item from Amazon. Any articles or standards that I should review would be greatly appreciated in order to understand this issue a little better.

How much data are you actually sending? How is the data divided into packets? For an extreme example, if you put one character in each packet then your latency should be very low but at high speeds the number of packets will be very high, resulting in a huge amount of overhead. On the other hand, if you put 1,500 characters in each packet and don't send packets until they are either full or a few hundred milliseconds have passed then you will have high latency at low speeds and low latency at high speeds. Need more details.

Does the processor not have Ethernet such that this could be done without an unknown/3rd party adapter? Have you attached any monitoring to the USB (cable, software stack?)? Can you analyze the adapter any other way (e.g. plug it into a PC and test loopback)? Outside chance: can you find a datasheet for the chipset used in the adapter?

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Unfortunately, I don't have this info as to how much data is being sent or how large the packets are. I will ping our software team about this to get more details.

@TimWilliams Somewhat unconventional, but the Ethernet interface on the Sitara processor connects directly to an FPGA. I think we have a cable that is a USB Micro to standard USB connector lying around. It would be a good test to validate the USB Adapter through a loopback test to cross the COTs item as a potential problem. I plan on probing the USB Data lines to confirm the signals are acceptable at high and low data rates.

@Oscyzilla So why think this is a USB or HW problem, instead of software, OS, or IP stack issue?

@Oscyzilla A lot of USB/Ethernet adapters rely on software emulation to replicate hardware performance, try it on a PCI adapter.
